# Does Déjà Dup remove deleted files when it makes an incremental backup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Say a file is deleted after a full backup but before the next incremental backup. When incrementing the backup, will Déjà Dup remove the deleted file from the backup? Is there any way to recover the deleted file after an incremental backup?

Comment: You can get the deleted file from the next-to-the-last backup assuming it existed at the time that backup was taken. The program does not troll backwards through all the backups removing deleted files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The short answer is **no**.

Dejadup does not modify the full backup after the backup is made. The incremental backup may make a note that a file does not exist on the day of the incremental backup, but the backed up version in the full backup is still there.

## Let us go through an example

Let's say you have 5 files, A, B, C, D, and E. On the new year of 2021 you make a resolution to regularly backup your files, and setup Dejadup to backup every week.

On January 1, 2021 Dejadup backs up A, B, C, D, and E. This is a full backup.

On January 3, you delete the file B. You create a new file F.

On January 8, dejadup does an incremental backup. This backup contains a note, that the file B does not exist anymore. The backup only contains file F.

Now there are two scenarios:

### A full recovery

Let's say your hard drive crashes on January 10. You get a new hard drive and install Ubuntu. Then you restore your files from dejadup backup to the most recent date, which is January 8. Dejadup will restore A, C, D, and E from the full backup and file F from the incremental backup as it will see the note in the incremental backup made on January 8, and know not to restore file B. You will get all the files as they were on January 8.

### Selected file recovery

You are lucky and your hard drive did not crash. However, on January 10 you realize that you need the file B after all. What you do is the following:

1. Open Nautlius, also known as Gnome **Files** and go to the folder where the file B was.
2. Right click on the empty space in that folder. Don't right click on any existing file. Select **Restore missing files...** from the bottom of the context menu.

[image]

You will see something like the above picture. It may take a while for Dejadup if you have lots of deleted files and backups going back years. So be patient.

3. Select file B from January 1, 2021 from this menu by marking the checkbox next to it and then click on **Forward**:

[image]

You will see something like the above picture. Click on the Green **Restore** button, and your lost file B will be back!

Hope this helps

Comment: Is this recovery pattern valid for incremental backups too? Here is this file "F", that we created _after_ the initial full backup, and is present in the January 8th incremental backup (and _not_ in subsequent incremental backups, right?) Now let's say we delete "F" at the end of January. After a few weeks pass, at the end of February, we want to recover "F". Can we recover "F" too? Is it going to be fetched for us from the January 8th incremental backup?

Comment: Also, is there a point to make a new full backup sometime later? Like, half a year, or a year later? Would it have benefits? Or is it unnecessary? Can Deja-dup handle that? Or would it be a new "backup project"?

Comment: By default it makes a new full backup every 90 days.

Comment: @Levente yes. you can recover F from the January 8 incremental backup if you delete it at a later date as long as that incremental backup exists.

Comment: @Levente Deja Dup occasionally make a full backup just in case any of the incremental backups are corrupted. Since the incremental backups build on each other, a since buggy backup makes every incremental backup following it unusable. Occasionally doing a full backup limits the number of backups that could be lost in such a situation.

Comment: @DennisAldea "Since the incremental backups build on each other, a since buggy backup makes every incremental backup following it unusable." — I'm with you, this is how I too imagine things would work. That's why it's so mind-boggling to see git work, and work so reliable! How. do. they. do. that. :) Then what should we think about blockchain in this regard, and crypto, even?! How can their incremental operations be more stable (or just more ambitious?) than Deja-dup's?

Comment: @Levente Bitcoin is a distributed network, transactions have to be independently verified by a consensus of nodes in the Bitcoin network. Network attacks are possible, especially on smaller cryptocurrencies, but unintentional errors are caught by the consensus filter.